# How to use web usercontrol multiple times on same web page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created one user control to pick date from calendar. I used jquery plugin to create it. My problem is when i put user control on aspx page its not working properly. I mean to say if i put two times than only one control working second one gives me an error.. so what will be issue??

Code which i have written to register jquery from code behind file

```
 string jquery = string.Empty;
    jquery = "window.addEvent('domready', function () { new CalendarEightysix('exampleIII', { 'excludedWeekdays': [0, 6], 'toggler': 'imgClick', 'offsetY': -4 });});   ";


    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + jquery + "</script>");
```

User Control Code.

```
<script src="JS/mootools-1.2.4-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JS/mootools-1.2.4.4-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JS/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="CSS/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<table cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <asp:Label ID="lblHeading" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input id="exampleIII" name="dateIII" readonly="readonly" type="text" maxlength="10"
        style="padding-right: 15px;" />
      <img src="Images/calendar.gif" alt="" id="imgClick" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any idea about this than please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give us more to work with, there are so many possible reasons why it's not working. Show us some code

Comment: I am ready to bet you are using the wrong jquery selectors(an id probably) to show that calendar.

Comment: @freefaller: see my question..I have updated it..

Comment: Doesn't tell much. I don't know about the CalendarEightysix, but how will it figure which asp.net control should it show the calendar for? You would usually need the use the ClientId of your asp.net web control.

Comment: @nunespascal: I have used it in web user control...So it will take same id...ya you are right..but how can i give different id??

Comment: @nunespascal: I am not using asp control..instead of it i am using simple img tag of html.

Comment: To replace the image tag, you can use a simple linkButton, and put the image as a background using css. Again, you would need to use the `ClientID` of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is for sure because your did not have place dynamic control id in  your control, or dynamic javascript initialize. With out change the ID on the more than one usercontrol loading then you have conflict when you try to use javascript.

To make dynamic IDs you can use the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) attribute of the same control.

On code, the points that you need to make dynamic change are, first of all the input that you select to be simple html control, add at the end of your ID the Current UserControl ID as:

```
<input id="exampleIII<%=ClientID%>" name="dateIII<%=ClientID%>" readonly="readonly"
```

and on

```
<img src="Images/calendar.gif" alt="" id="imgClick<%=ClientID%>" />
```

Then you change your javascript as:

```
 string jquery = string.Empty;
    jquery = "window.addEvent('domready', function () { new CalendarEightysix('exampleIII"+ ClientID + "', { 'excludedWeekdays': [0, 6], 'toggler': 'imgClick"+ ClientID + "', 'offsetY': -4 });});   ";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "akey"+ClientID, "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + jquery + "</script>");
```

and load your common javascript library only ones, maybe on master page, or use the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

ps: use the `id="exampleIII<%=ClientID%>"` to render your controls because the `ClientID` by him self alone is all ready used. So you get a name a final name with both ClientID and exampleIII.

An alternative is to make the buttons asp.net controls because using the `<%= %>` you have issues with UpdatePanels. If you make them asp.net controls then you get the `ControlName.CliendID` to use on the javascript init

Comment: date picker opening two times while i am putting code as like yours

Comment: @user968441 This is the idea, I do not debug your code to see this details... see what renders on, is open in both text editors ?

Comment: @user968441 also change the name id.

Comment: Your idea works man...have also applied ClientId to imgClick and problem solved....Its like bingoooooooo....thank you so much... :)

Comment: @user968441 An alternative is to make the buttons asp.net controls because using the <%=%> you have issues with UpdatePanels. If you make  them asp.net controls then you get the `ControlName.CliendID` to use on the javascript init

Comment: Yes but in my case i have to use html control...asp controls not allow :( ...thats y...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13612/discussion-between-user968441-and-aristos)

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for client-side problems when multiple UserControls are included in a page is the use of HTML markup with fixed ids.  This results in elements with duplicate ids when you include the UserControl more than once.

Without seeing code it's not possible to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this id `exampleIII` in your javascript code. Use a textbox instead of the input tag.

There you need to use the asp.net `ClientID`.

Change your control as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="exampleIII" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID="imgClick" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Something like this:

```
jquery = "window.addEvent('domready', function () { new CalendarEightysix('" + exampleIII.ClientID + "', { 'excludedWeekdays': [0, 6], 'toggler': '" + imgClick.ClientID + "', 'offsetY': -4 });});   ";


Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + jquery + "</script>");
```

Refer: [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)

> When a Web server control is rendered as an HTML element, the id
>   attribute of the HTML element is set to the value of the ClientID
>   property. The ClientID value is often used to access the HTML element
>   in client script by using the document.getElementById method.